# New install -- no wifi drivers, no wifi icon, nothing

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu (for the first time) on a brand new Lenovo Yoga 6, with a Ryzen 5 AMD chip. Ubuntu 20.04.3, Gnome 3.36.8.

Everything installed perfectly, except there is no wireless, at all. I looked at some forums and ran some commands, and basically confirmed this.

I am only able to get it to connect via phone tethering (because it has no ethernet port). Can't seem to find appropriate drivers to install.

I don't have the terminal history (having restarted the computer and tried some BIOS boot stuff several times) and can't find the articles I followed, but I tried a number of commands (some below) that would ideally have unearthed some drivers, with no luck.

Thanks!

Some debugging attempts:

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5008 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8852
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164c (rev c2)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
04:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
04:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

**sudo service network-manager restart**
(no effect)

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0700000-c07fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 0a:85:f9:a1:25:d3
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.79.33 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml**

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

Comment: Thanks for the response. 3 questions. 

The repo says "IF YOU RUN UBUNTU, YOU CAN BE ASSURED THAT THE APIs HAVE CHANGED. NO, I WILL NOT MODIFY THE SOURCE FOR YOU. YOU ARE ON YOUR OWN!!!!!" Am I not running Ubuntu?

It also says it's for "Realtek 8852AE". Do I have this card? How do I know?

Third: Do I risk anything here?

Comment: You genius, it worked!